# Error dismissing SwiftUI ColorPicker : "Connection to plugin interrupted while in use"

Tags: plugins, colors, swiftui, picker

I keep getting this warning after dismissing the Color Picker in SwiftUI:

*[lifecycle] [u 17309674-CE1F-40CF-AD78-169944F5137B:m (null)] [com.apple.UIKit.ColorPicker(1.0)] **Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.***

Am I the only one? I've had it since early SwiftUI versions and thought it was a bug on their part, but I keep seeing it even after updating to latest versions of the kit...

... Must be me? I don't see what I do wrong though, I'm using the UI component pretty straightforwardly

Any ideas? Here's the basic code:

```
@EnvironmentObject var selectedColor: SelectedColor
...
ColorPicker("Tool Color", selection: $selectedColor.value, supportsOpacity: true)
```

Comment: Would you show your code?

Comment: I've updated my post with the code

Comment: I see the same issue

Comment: I get this issue also `viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}`

Comment: Getting the error message too. SwiftUI is completely buggy.

Comment: I see the same error using UIKit

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems resolved with SwiftUI 3.0